# Unknown column GroupBy1.K1 in field list

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

First off, this worked with MSSQL Server but we've switched over to MySQL and now it isn't working.

I have a simple query which returns total values based off a certain year.

It looks like this:

```
  public Dictionary<string, decimal> GetYearValues(int[] SupplierID) {
            _ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60;

            var Total = (from x in _ctx.Invoices
                         where x.Turnover == true &&
                         SupplierID.Contains(x.FK_SupplierID)
                         group x by new { x.InvoiceDate.Year } into summ
                         select new {
                             Year = summ.Key.Year,
                             TurnOver = summ.Sum(s => s.NetAmount_Home ?? 0)
                         }).ToDictionary(x => x.Year.ToString(), x => x.TurnOver);

            return Total;
        }
```

I've noticed that nothing is wrong with the query, it's only the ToDictionary which fails and gives the error message. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @HariPrasad It's in the title